# connectedcallback vs renderedcallback in lightning web component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, lightning-experience

I'm new to Salesforce LWC. I'm trying to understand the LWC component life cycle methods. But it is a bit difficult to understand. Can any give a simple explanation about connectedcallback() and renderedcallback() methods with simple example in LWC?

Answer (score 23):

### connectedcallback()

The connected callback is executed when the component is inserted into DOM. Connected callback runs once when the component is inserted. If you know aura components then this is similar to aura init handler.

> The `connectedCallback()` hook can fire more than once. For example, if
> you remove an element and then insert it into another position, such
> as when you reorder a list, the hook fires several times. If you want
> code to run one time, write code to prevent it from running twice.

We generally use it when we need to do something when the component is loaded. For eg. query some data when the component is loaded.

The execution flow of `connectedCallback` is parent to child. So you cannot access child elements in the `connectedCallback`, because they are not inserted yet.

**Example:**

**parentComponent.js**

```
connectedCallback() {
    console.log('parent inserted');
}
```

**childComponent.js**

```
connectedCallback() {
    console.log('child inserted');
}
```

**parentComponent.html**

```
<c-parent-component>
   <c-child-component></c-child-component>
</c-parent-component>
```

If we run the above code, then the console logs will be like below:

```
parent inserted
child inserted
```

### renderedcallback()

This gets called when the component is rendered. Basically when all the elements on the component are inserted.

> A component is rerendered when the value of a property changes and
> that property is used either directly in a component template or
> indirectly in the getter of a property that is used in a template. See
> Reactivity.

The meaning of above statement from the docs is that, the component is rerendered when any reactive property is changed. For. eg. The property with `@track`, `@api`, `@wire`, with getter setter and any premitive property which is member of component class. The component reevaluate all the expression based on the new data in the reactive properties.

Most common example of `renderedCallback()` is that we use to load the static resources.(write code to prevent it from running twice).

The execution flow of `renderedcallback` is child to parent, means the `renderedcallback` of all childs are called before the parent's.

### Points to remember:

- The `connectedCallback()` hook can fire more than once. For example, if you remove an element and then insert it into another position. If you want code to run one time, write code to prevent it from running twice
- Child components are not available in the `connectedCallback()`.
- Don’t update a wire adapter configuration object property in `renderedCallback()`
- Don’t update a public property or field in `renderedCallback()`

There are other nuances which you can find in the below mentioned links.

### Important References

[Run Code When a Component Is Inserted or Removed from the DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_lifecycle_hooks_dom) 
[Run Code When a Component Renders](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_lifecycle_hooks_rendered) 
[Lifecycle Flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_lifecycle_hooks)

Comment: Can you provide an example when connected callback runs more than once?

Comment: @MichaelMunta If you have a sub-component that is shown/hidden based on `if:true={condition}` then the `connectedCallback` is called every time the component is made visible. Similarly the `disconnectedCallback` is called every time component is hidden.

Comment: @MichaelMunta [Here](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/TTkaR3y9HmpX88ZcO5W5/src/app.js) is the live example, toggle the Show box and check the console logs.

Comment: Oh, I thought that the hook would fire on the parent as well because it sounded like a warning. But in essence it only fires **once each time** the component is added to the DOM?

Comment: @MichaelMunta yes correct each time the component is added and reordered.